# Parse Error: invalid login parameters (Code: 101, Version: 1.10.0)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to login in iOS using parse.com. But, during the login, an error is occurring every time. I found the solution for that, but still the error is continuing. My code is:

```
 if (![self.phonnumber.text  isEqual: @""]){
    if(![self.emailtxt.text isEqual: @""])
    {
        NSString *userEmail = @"abc@gmail.com";//self.emailtxt.text;
        NSString *userPassword = @"123";//self.phonnumber.text;

        [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:userEmail
                                     password:userPassword block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
         {
             if (!error) {

                 NSLog(@"succes");
             } else {
                 // The login failed. Check error to see why.
             }
         }];
    }
```

Comment: username key should be @"abc@gmail.com" in parse user

Comment: i just pass the email and password.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KQfRM.png

Comment: Thank you. Its done.But if  i want to add new entry of user then what method is use .

Answer (score 1):

LoginwithUsername is expecting username not the email value.

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:@"frank" //username value in parse user table
                                             password:@"123" block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
                 {
                     if (!error) {

                         NSLog(@"succes");
                     } else {
                         // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                     }
                 }];
```

if you want to keep it working with email then while registration set email value against username and email both. and for display purpose if you need user name then set that in another key like displayName or FullName